# Labeled CAR point cloud KITTI

Tags: point-cloud-library, point-clouds, lidar, kitti

I am trying to identify objects in a point cloud using this [tutorial](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/correspondence_grouping.php#correspondence-grouping) from PCL. I am using Kitti Dataset. For this tutorial I need a point cloud scan of the object I am trying to identify. So  in my case, the kitti scans contain 3D point clouds with cars, bus, trams, cyclists etc in an urban environment, I need a point cloud scan of a car so that I can compare with that and detect cars in the environment scan. Is there anyway to extract only the scan of one particular object from a point cloud scene? I looked into it and I can't find any that work in my case. I looked into open3d which has a crop function but i don't have the cropped.json file that is needed for that. Or if anyone already did something like this and you have guidance or the cropped vehicle data saved I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0):

This could be of some use, check this out -

https://github.com/jhultman/vision3d

You can get more references from below -

https://paperswithcode.com/task/3d-object-detection